# Make SVG render after loading CSS (React styled-components)

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, styled-components, gatsby

I am building a landing page with GatsbyJS and Styled-Components where I wish to display a SVG logo in the center of the screen.

After deploying to server, it appears that when loading my page, the SVG gets loaded first and immediately rendered to the upper-left corner of the screen, apparently before the CSS which makes it jumps to the center after a noticeable latency.

This is how I am doing this:

```
// import "styled" and React
import logo from '../images/logo.svg'

const CenterDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
`
const Logo = styled.img`
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 1.5rem solid black;
`
const IndexPage = () => (
  <CenterDiv>
    <Logo src={logo} alt="Logo" />
  </CenterDiv>
)

export default IndexPage
```

How can I get the SVG loaded after the CSS, so that the users don't see the logo jump around?

I have also installed the "gatsby-plugin-styled-components" package, which let's styled-components render on server side/build-time.

Thank you!

Edit: I moved the styles to the styles prop in React components, which seems to have fixed this asynchronous issue. However, I still would like to know how to do this with styled-components, because I can write normal CSS and media queries there.

Note: In this context, I am using Gatsby/React and prefer CSS-in-JS solutions. I have similar issues when using "styled-components" in other situations too - the content gets loaded first while styles applied afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

> After deploying to server, it appears that when loading my page, the
>   SVG gets loaded first and immediately rendered to the upper-left
>   corner of the screen, apparently before the CSS which makes it jumps
>   to the center after a noticeable latency.

One approach would be using a CSS class to ensure that the SVG remains invisible until the window fully loads, after which it becomes visible.

**E.g.**

1) Add an initial class to the SVG which renders it invisible:

**HTML:** `<svg class="logo hide">`

**CSS:** `svg.hide {opacity: 0;}`

---

2) Then apply an `onload` Event Listener to the window:

```
window.addEventListener('load', removeOpacityFromSVG, false);

function removeOpacityFromSVG() {

    var logoSVG = document.getElementsByClassName('logo')[0];
    logoSVG.className = 'logo';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in this context, I am using React and prefer CSS-in-JS solutions. I have similar issues when using styled-components in other places too - the content gets loaded first while styles applied afterwards.

Comment: How is the style being applied to the element? If not via a stylesheet, then via an inline `style=" [...] "` attribute? In which case, instead of rewriting `logoSVG.className` after onload, simply rewrite `logoSVG.style`. eg. After `onload` you can grab the contents of the `style` attribute, remove `opacity: 0;` and replace the contents of the `style` attribute.

Comment: The style is applied to React components via a CSS-in-JS package "styled-components", as explained and seen in my code examples.

Comment: As far as I know, using `onload` is not encouraged in React. I think this issue is specific to styled-components. Please see my edit and note to the original question.